# Scheme (Lazy Racket) an infinite list of natural numbers

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, lazy-evaluation, infinite

I think that [Lazy Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/) should be useful for handling infinite lists. According to the [Wikipedia Lazy Racket article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_features#Lazy_Racket), `fibs` (the infinite list of Fibonacci numbers) can be defined as:

```
;; An infinite list:
(define fibs (list* 1 1 (map + fibs (cdr fibs))))
```

How do we define an infinite list of natural numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#lang lazy
(define Nat (cons 1 (map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) Nat)))
```

thanks to Will Ness.

I also found

```
#lang lazy
;;; infinite sequences represented by a_(n+1) = f(a_n)
(define inf-seq (lambda (a0 f) (cons a0 (inf-seq (f a0) f))))
(define Nat (inf-seq 1 (lambda (x) (+ x 1))))
```

To output

```
(define (outputListData list)
   (cond 
       [(null? list) #f] ; actually doesn't really matter what we return
       [else 
            (printf "~s\n" (first list)) ; display the first item ...
            (outputListData (rest list))] ; and start over with the rest
    )
)

(outputListData Nat)
```

Comment: for comparison, in Haskell it is known as `iterate` (Haskell's got really good names for such functions): `iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x)`. And for "output" it has ``take n [] = [] ; take 0 xs = [] ; take n (x:xs) = x : take (n-1) xs``. (`a:b` in Haskell is like `(a . b)` in Scheme). So `nats = iterate (1+) 1` and we see first 10 of them with `take 10 nats`. Racket too has `take`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#lang lazy

(define nats (cons 1 (map 1+ nats)))
```

Apparently this doesn't work, and `1+` should be replaced by `(lambda (x) (+ x 1))`. Thanks to @kenokabe for testing. (`add1` is the proper name.)

Comment: (define Nat (cons 1 (map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) Nat)))  Ok you meant this, thanks.

Comment: @kenokabe what was the error, could you please show it/copy it here?

Comment: 1+: unbound identifier in module in: 1+

Comment: I think '1+' is not defined in the language system.

Comment: 1+ is called add1 in Racket. Maybe in Lazy Racket as well?

Comment: @Sylwester thanks, guys. I thought `1+` was in R5RS at least, but seems it's not.

Comment: Use `add1` -- the name that is used in Racket.  (`1+` is not standard, and looking at R5RS for answers is pointless in this case.)